# Leaflet en el movil

Tags: javascript, leaflet

seré breve

mapa en leaflet que funciona perfectamente en el Ordenador portatil pero en  telefono móvil, se queda en blanco...

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition( success, error, options );
var coordenadas = position.coords;


function success(position) {

var coordenadas = position.coords;


  var Lat= coordenadas.latitude ;
  var Lon = coordenadas.longitude;

// Inicializamos el mapa
    var map = L.map('map').
    setView( [Lat, Lon],12);

// El titulo de la Capa

    L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a 

href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>',
    maxZoom: 18
    }).addTo(map);

// ponemos un control para escalar el mapa  
    L.control.scale().addTo(map);




// Ponemos un marcador
    var marker = L.marker([ Lat , Lon ],{draggable: true}).addTo(map);  

    marker.bindPopup("Situacion").openPopup();




};
```

he comprobado que en los telefonos móviles, y parece que no funciona `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition`, no devuelve las coordenadas, y si lo hace cuando utilizo el ordenador portátil.

si teneis alguna idea,alguna pista, rumor, cuchicheo, y sobre todo una solución, por Dios, hacedmela saber, y seré vuestro mas fiel servidor.......
Saludos

Answer (score 0):

despues de mucho leer, la solución es........ Servidor seguro por https.....ni media palabra más, por https.. perfecto.

saludos